# Open source software - How to setup files

Tags: php, file, filesystems

I'm in the middle of making my own custom forum system software. Much like phpbb, mybb, vbulletin, etc. except it's obviously quite less advanced. It's just a personal project for myself and I've run into some problems since I've never had to develop something that can be repackaged for others.

The file structure is as follows:

[image: File Structure]

So, config.php is the end all be all of including files. It has the database connection information, it instantiates my database class as well, and none of the function files require/include any files since they'll always be accessed where config.php is required.

HERE'S THe QUESTION!
However I'm running into simple but very annoying problems, for example I call a function in config.php towards the top that checks the users cookies values and makes sure they all belong to the same user, and if not it deletes the cookies. However, it has to be after the database files require. And things like, a variable declared in config.php isn't always accessible, so sometimes I have to declare it in the header files.

Seems like it's not much of a question, but I guess it's just asking for how I can include/require in general without running into issues.

Comment: You probably have to be more specific to get any good answers ...

Answer (score 0):

As a general note, most people don't mix config variables and code in one file. If you look at popular open source packages like Wordpress, Config.php just has config variables set. No code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using certain functions in anything more than a "one off" situation, you may want to consider putting them into your main class - that way they're available as needed.

@James is right, separate your config file. You can include it inside an "application.php" required file (so it's available globally).

I have run into a situation where I absolutely needed HTTP Header information prior to page build. Though it seemed a little backward, the solution was to call that file first, then include the application.php file. Checking for a cookie should be fine.

In another situation, @include('myStubbonPricing.php') was the answer. I'm not an advocate of error suppression, but in my case it only outputted a shipping rate (if the zip code was entered). To my defense !isset and the like would not fix the problem due to an XML request/response scenario.